# Autocmd not running execute when calling function

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm working on a small vim plugin and needed to add an `autocmd` to call one of my functions `MakeMatch` whenever Insert mode is exited.

The actual setup to get the function to be called is pretty simple:

```
augroup Poi
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertLeave * call s:MakeMatch()
augroup END
```

Originally I was under the impression that the function wasn't being called but then I added an `echo` into the definition and saw the string printed out.

The function is essentially the following:

```
function! s:MakeMatch()
  "Iterate and create g:build_string up
  "g:build_string=":match poi /\%5l\|\%6l/"
  execute g:build_string
endfunction
```

If I was to `:call s:MakeMatch()` the build string will successfully execute as I had expected when leaving insert mode..

I've seen code in other plugins that uses `au * exec..` without issue. I'm wondering if this is an issue with calling match during `InsertLeave`; I could definitely see something calling `hi clear` or maybe highlighting just isnt allowed during `InsertLeave`.

Been playing around with this with a co-worker and haven't been able to get it to run the match. We tried calling the match directly and other types of execute.. Would love to get some more info on why this may not be working.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Here's the [full code for the plugin](https://github.com/DanBradbury/vim-poi) I've wrote. It's working as expected now :D

Comment: You can certainly do this. Simple test case: `autocmd InsertLeave * match Search /./`. This will work without any issue. So more than likely it is how you build up your `g:build_string`. (Should this variable really be global?) Note: `InsertLeave` will not trigger when using `<c-c>` to exit insert mode. See `:h InsertLeave`.

Comment: Can you show the code to build the string? As posted your code works (if you change poi to a highlight group that exists)

Comment: So I've found out that adding the command into the file doesn't have it execute properly. If I do `:au InsertLeave * match Search /./` it will work like a charm. Not sure why it wont respond to it in the file itself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't got confirmation that this is the "correct" approach but it's the one that worked for me..

1. Removed the `augroup` and simply define an `autocmd` that will execute properly when vim loads my plugin's `.vim` file.
2. `autocmd InsertLeave * call s:MakeMatch()` was a little off the mark for a few reasons. The most obvious being that `<SID>` should have been used when attempting to call the function.

As an aside; @Peter Rinker: Mentioned trying to run `autocmd InsertLeave * match Search /./.` which works like a charm when running in `:Ex` mode but if you try to define the `au!` within the plugin/vimrc file it won't work..
I think this might have something to do with the fact that `match` is not an `eval` function but I am not sure if that is actually the case.

3. Ensure it ran as an `Ex` command. Since I had to run the command rather than have it be defined I had to change to `{event}` and call `execute` with the `:` like I had done to get @Peter's suggestion to work.

`au! VimEnter * execute(":autocmd InsertLeave * call <SID>MakeMatch()")`

The above did the trick for me but I'd definitely be interested in any other approach/more info.